# Почему на StackOverlow не добавляют спойлеры?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Почему на StackOverlow не добавляют спойлеры?

Она нужна чтобы скрывать много текста и меет заголовок, если нажать на заголовок от открывается список вниз и там этот текст.

Вообще спойлеры нужны чтобы уменшать слишком большие картинки или текст. Это очень удобно чем пол часа крутить колесико на мыши, до такого состояния чтобы на след. день купить новую мышку.

Comment: Плохо, что не добавляют что-то вроде [**Clipboard.js**](https://clipboardjs.com/) для быстрого копирования кода из сообщений. Спасибо.